# Can I use a PNG point marker?

Tags: qgis, style

I want to style a point layer from png file. Can i do this in quantum gis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: No (not yet anyway)

Other answer: However you can use a SVG. So you can just convert the png to svg and use that instead *(note: untested)*